# Scrapy: Multiple crawler in one project

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a web crawler using scrapy with proxies. Since I always need a pool of random proxies to avoid being banned, I decide to write another crawler that scrapes a website providing free available IPs.

Currently, I have the two spiders in two separate scrapy projects with different settings, pipelines and middlewares. Every time I start the crawling process, I need to scrape for the IPs first, export them to a file, and then go to the root directory of the other crawler and read the IPs into setting.py. I wonder if it is possible to combine two spiders into one single project so that I only have to run one command to start the whole crawling process.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 spiders in 1 project but you'd have to run 2 different commands anyway to crawl. What you can do is create a script that starts the process independently.

```
import subprocess
p1=subprocess.Popen(["scrapy","crawl", "spider"])
p2=subprocess.Popen(["scrapy","crawl", "spider2"])
```

You can even pass arguments to it such as the IPs that you were refering to

```
p=subprocess.Popen(["scrapy","crawl", "spider", "-a", "website='Newton.ai'"])
```